# Does this use of new create a memory leak?

Tags: c++

I saw a use of `new` today that I'm not familiar with.

```
{
    string * test = new string("bye");
    new (test) string("hello");
    cout << *test << endl; //prints "hello"

    delete test;
}
```

It seemed like it should at first, but if I try and "remember" the initial value of `test`, it looks like the memory gets reallocated:

```
string * test = new string("bye");
string * test2 = test;
new (test) string("hello");
cout << *test << endl; //prints "hello"
cout << *test2 << endl; //also prints "hello"
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to demonstrate with your second example. Why *wouldn't* `cout<< * test2` print hello?

Comment: Placement new, and yes, it leaks because the destructor for the original object is not run.

Comment: @megar because I've assigned `test2` to the original value of `test`. If new memory is allocated by the second `new` statement, the value of `test` should change. But it doesn't.

Comment: given just this code, the only thing I see missing is *manual* firing of the destructor before the placement; something warranted when using placement-new (and oddly, something *none* of the answers below mention).

Comment: @WhozCraig So then, if I added a `test->~string();` before my placement new, there would be no possible memory leak? Also, does that mean anything with a trivial destructor can be constructed over with a placement new without worry?

Comment: @RedAlert yes, and referring to your second snippet, both `test` and `test2` would point to the same reconstructed `std::string` object (which now contains `"hello"`) when this finished unless it is as Cheer's mentioned and some fiend overloaded `operator new` for `std::string`. Be sure to only `delete` **one** of them. Placement-new is something you want to approach with care for precisely the reasons Cheers mentioned. Only when *you* have solid knowledge of `operator new`   for the underlying type should you do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a potential memory leak, but not because the reason you might be thinking, that there are two `new`s and only one `delete`. That's actually just fine.

The problem is that the first string's destructor is never run. Any internal memory it's allocated is never deallocated.

To explain, the second `new` is what's called **placement `new`**. It's a way of calling a constructor on memory that's already been allocated. *(This is an oversimplification, but let's not get sidetracked. You know where Google is if you want to read up more on placement `new`.)* The effect of `new (test) string("hello")` is that it overwrites the first string (`"bye"`) with another one (`"hello"`). The placement `new` doesn't allocate any more memory. It just runs the `string::string(const char *)` constructor on the existing memory area.

And that's why the program prints `hello` twice. `test` and `test2` are both pointing to the same string, so when you overwrite that string the change shows up in both variables. The variables themselves haven't changed, but the object they're pointing to has.

Comment: nitpick: if there is an overload of `operator new` that accepts a `std::string*`, then doesn't necessarily return that pointer. illustrating both the danger of providing incomplete code (as the OP did), and the danger of teaching specifics (the OP might later encounter code where the distinction matters).

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I've put in a note that my answer is oversimplified for pedagogical purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have a (<sup>*</sup>likely) memory leak. And no, the checking code doesn't demonstrate otherwise. It demonstrates that both pointers you have point to the same object.

---

To understand this, note that a `std::string` *generally* stores the text somewhere else, in a buffer that it allocates dynamically.

Thus when you `new` a `std::string`, there are at least two dynamic allocations:

- Dynamic allocation of the `std::string` object itself.
- That object's dynamic allocation of a string buffer.

The memory leak is about the buffer, which is not deallocated because the first `std::string` object's destructor is not run.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup>) “Likely” instead of certain because a `std::string`, in contrast to a `std::vector`, may employ a short buffer optimization where it stores the data directly.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is called placement new. It calls the constructor on a block of already allocated memory.

Since the original object was never destroyed, it could certainly lead to a memory leak. If it didn't, it's perhaps because short strings are contained within the object itself and don't cause an allocation for the string buffer.